# Why can't I query my DataMapper model?

Tags: ruby, orm, datamapper

I'm trying to query a column in my model here:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-aggregates'

db_name = 'mydb.sqlite'

DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite://' + Dir.pwd + '/' + db_name)

class Context
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,         Serial
  property :order,      Integer

  def initialize
    self.order = (self.class.max(:order) || 0) + 1
  end

  def move_up
    temp = self.class.first(:order => (self.order - 1))
    temp.order += 1
    temp.save
    self.order -= 1
    self.save
  end

end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

But when I create a couple of instances I'm getting the following error when I call the `move_up` method.

```
Failure/Error: context2.move_up
+options[:order]+ entry 1 of an unsupported object Fixnum
# ./context.rb:11:in `move_up'
```

Edge conditions notwithstanding, why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:order is a reserved word as it's one of the options that you pass to a query. just rename it to something different and it will work

Comment: Ugh, forehead smack.  Thanks again solnic.

Comment: Heh :) btw - I just made a change that will make Property to scream at you if you try to use one of the query options as a property name, like :order, :fields etc. 

You can check out the commit to see which names are reserved:

https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/commit/ea8d92b48af431a3197a8d589730e0f638709cad

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I'll be looking forward to the gem update.  Enjoying using dm.